# Subjunctive and past tense

Tags: grammar

Which form is correct:
*If I sent you a workout plan, it would be because I love you.*
Or should it be:
*If I sent you a workout plan it would be because I loved you.*
My gut says it should be *loved* because I want to make the tense agree with *would*

Comment: How about including a link on "subjunctive" and explaining how it applies to your question?

Comment: You can aver that you know what's best for your sweetheart for the love you feel. But were the subjunctive to get you out of hot water for suggesting someone needs to exercise, ah!

Comment: I encourage you to look through questions with the [subjunctive] tag, and welcome to EL&U.  There's a very similar question here.

Comment: My gut says it would be "love" because it is an enduring state, not one that has ended. It is also not directly part of the if-then construction so I don't think sequence of tenses is as strict.

Comment: Just be consistent. EITHER *If I **sent** you a workout plan, it **would** be because I **loved** you.* OR *If I **send** you a workout plan, it **will** be because I **love** you.*

Comment: Never, ever, ever end a message to a loved one with the phrase _I loved you_. The correct way to end such a message is in the present tense.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't backshift the verb *love* in the subordinate clause, leaving it in the present tense, it would imply that the same "modal remoteness" applying to *would be* does not extend to *love* also. In other words:

> 1. If I sent you a workout plan, it would be because I love you.
> 2. If I sent you a workout plan it would be because I loved you.

Sentence (1) implies that you love the addressee *now.* Sentence (2) implies that the love would occur only in the hypothetical situation where you send the workout plan.